# JRuby "no such file to load"

Tags: ruby, rubygems, jruby, bundler

Using jruby-1.6.7 via rvm and gem version 1.8.24 I created a new project containing a Gemfile:

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'
gem 'google-api-client'
```

and a main.rb:

```
require 'google/api_client'
```

After

```
gem install bundler
bundle install
gem list
```

I get

```
addressable (2.2.8)
autoparse (0.3.1)
bouncy-castle-java (1.5.0146.1)
bundler (1.1.4)
extlib (0.9.15)
faraday (0.8.1, 0.7.6)
ffi (1.0.11 java)
google-api-client (0.4.3)
jruby-launcher (1.0.14 java)
jruby-openssl (0.7.7)
json (1.7.3 java)
jwt (0.1.4)
launchy (2.1.0 java)
multi_json (1.3.6)
multipart-post (1.1.5)
rack (1.4.1)
rake (0.9.2.2)
rubygems-bundler (1.0.2)
rubygems-update (1.8.24, 1.7.2)
rvm (1.11.3.3)
signet (0.3.4)
spoon (0.0.1)
```

But when I run ruby main.rb, it results in an error:

```
LoadError: no such file to load -- google/api_client
  require at org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1033
   (root) at main.rb:1
```

On MRI everything seems to be working fine. The problem does not seem bound to any specific gem.

Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unless you have `JRUBY_OPTS=--1.9` in your environment, or you pass the `--1.9` flag on the command line, JRuby will default to 1.8 mode, which means that you explicitly have to `require 'rubygems'` in `main.rb` before you load your gems.

Comment: Thanks for the edit suggestion. Generally speaking, though, if you are going to be using multiple Ruby vm's (you mentioned MRI), you would be better off forcing JRuby's `1.9` mode than adding the explicit `require`s. There are other differences between 1.8 and 1.9 that might trip you up in future.

Comment: starting with JRuby 1.7 (`rvm install jruby-1.7.0.preview1`) it defaults to **1.9**, or you could use `--1.9` to install jruby which would switch it also, not need for `JRUBY_OPTS=--1.9`.